# How to reduce the padding/margins of the Holo DatePicker & TimePicker?

Tags: android

Is it possible to make the Holo DatePicker & TimePicker smaller or reduce padding/margins? I'm having trouble getting elements to fit on the screen when I use `Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog` as the style. If I use `Theme.Dialog` as the style it all fits.

This is the dialog as it appears on the HTC One V (please excuse the pic of the phone, I couldn't get it to save screenshots):

[image]

You can see that the buttons are being clipped at the bottom. If the `DatePicker` & `TimePicker` didn't take up so much space it would all fit.

This is the dialog as it appears on the Galaxy S4 (for reference):

[image]

And this is how the `Theme.Dialog` appears on the HTC (you can see that there is no wasted space):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

easiest solution what I found was:
setting negative margin to date/time pickerView.

```
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-32dp"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem surely comes from the screen's size and Holo defines only one layout with raw margins (in DP).

Override the layout XML file [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/layout/date_picker_holo.xml) by importing it in your project's resources. Make sure to save the file in the folder corresponding to your phone's screen size.

Then, you'll be pleased to change the layout properties such as margins.

Answer (score 1):

For the Holo TimePicker you can use this.

```
public static void setTimePickerHeightTopBottomMargin(
        TimePicker timePicker, int height, int topMargin, int bottomMargin) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        try {
            Field f;
            View v;
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params;
            // mHourSpinner
            f = TimePicker.class.getDeclaredField("mHourSpinner");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            v = (View) f.get(timePicker);
            params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height;
            params.topMargin = topMargin;
            params.bottomMargin = bottomMargin;
            // mMinuteSpinner
            f = TimePicker.class.getDeclaredField("mMinuteSpinner");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            v = (View) f.get(timePicker);
            params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height;
            params.topMargin = topMargin;
            params.bottomMargin = bottomMargin;
            // mAmPmSpinner
            f = TimePicker.class.getDeclaredField("mAmPmSpinner");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            v = (View) f.get(timePicker);
            params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = height;
            params.topMargin = topMargin;
            params.bottomMargin = bottomMargin;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w(TAG, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Units are pixels so make sure to convert from dp. Don't use heights less than 120dp.

Keeping the height and removing the vertical margins should normally be sufficient:

```
setTimePickerHeightTopBottomMargin(mTimePicker,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0);
```

Although I've not tested it it should be the same for DatePicker by using reflection on fields `mDaySpinner`, `mMonthSpinner` and `mYearSpinner` instead.